# Generating AppID for Sencha Cordova Android app

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch-2, identification

I'm learning Sencha Touch and trying to deploy to actual devices.

Attempting to follow [this](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/guide/cordova) document and package an app for deployment, I'm lost regarding the AppID.

How can I acquire the AppID so I can package my app using the following code:

```
sencha cordova init ???
```

Answer (score 0):

App IDs, along with several other concepts such as certificates, bundles, and provisioning profiles, belong to Apple's mobile application development, testing and distribution process.

I strongly recommend you to read this first to have an overview understanding of how it works:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

When you do, the steps can be summarized to the following:

1. Register an Apple developer account.
2. Request for and then download a developer certificate.
3. Register App IDs (and generate a provisioning profile which includes it)